# How to make table with treeviewcheckbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have treeview - https://jsfiddle.net/allengosta/9pg13kth/11/
and i want to make **treetable** (first column - treeview, second column - color) like:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nicOK.png)

How to do this?

```
//json example

var treeObject = [
{
    text:"Parent 1",
    checked:true,
    id:15,
color: 'blue',
    children:[ // Required
        { text:"Child 1", checked:true, color: 'white'},
        { text:"Child 2", color: 'green'    }
    ]
},
{
    text:"Parent 2",
color: 'yellow',
    children:[
        {
            text:"Parent 3",
    color: 'purple',
            children:[
                {text:"Child 3",checked:true, color: 'green'},
                {text:"Child 4", color: 'orange'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**
This new solution uses an HTML Table element as you asked. The UI looks fine when I test it in Chrome, but it's not an ideal solution because it nests table rows directly within other table rows.(Getting the CSS right would be much more challenging without this kludge.) The `SPACER_WIDTH` hack in the `createSingleItem` function was my way of handling horizontal alignment in this context.

(If you don't really need a table per se, you could consider changing the `TR`s back to `UL`s and the and use some inline-block `LI`s with appropriate widths and such to keep everything aligned.)

Most of the significant changes are in the last two functions. I hope it works for you.

```js
// Constructs a TableTreeView from `testArray` and adds it to `container` 
  var testArray = [
    {
      text: "Parent 1",
      checked: true,
      id: 15,
      color: 'blue',
      children: [{ text: "Child 1", checked: true, color: 'white' }, { text: "Child 2", color: 'green' }]
    },
    {
      text: "Parent 2",
      color: 'yellow',
      children: [{
        text: "Parent 3",
        color: 'purple',
        children: [{ text: "Child 3", checked: true, color: 'green' }, { text: "Child 4", color: 'orange' }]
      }]
    }  
  ]
  var tw = new TableTreeView( testArray, { showAlwaysCheckBox: true, fold: false });
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tw.root);


  // ---------- TableTreeView constructor ----------
  function TableTreeView(datas, options) {

    // --- Makes `root` table (with class `.tabletreeview`) ---
    this.root = document.createElement("table");
    this.root.className = "tabletreeview";
    let t = this;

    // ---- Defines instance methods ----
    this.update = function() {
      $(t.root).find(".group").each(function(index, el) {
        if ($(el).find(".group").length > 0) { $(el).find(">[fold-button]").css("visibility", "visible"); }
        else { $(el).find(">[fold-button]").css("visibility", "hidden"); }
        checkControlParents.bind($(el).find(">.item"))();
      })
    }
    this.load = function(datas){
      $(this.root).empty();
      createTreeViewReq(this.root, datas, options, 0);
      this.update();
    }
    this.save = function(type, node){
      if(type == null){ type = "tree"; }
      if(type == "tree"){
        if(node == null){
          var data = [], $children = $(this.root).find(">.group");
          for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i++) { var child = this.save("tree", $children[i]); data.push(child); }
          return data;
        }
        else {
          var data = saveSingle($(node).find(">.item")[0]);
          data.children = [];
          var $children = $(node).find(">.group");
          for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i++){ var child = this.save("tree", $children[i]); data.children.push(child); }
          return data;
        }
      }
      if (type == "list") {
        var data = [], $items = $(this.root).find(".item");
        for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) { data.push(saveSingle($items[i])); }
        return data;
      }
    }
    this.openAllFold = function(item) {
      item = item ||this.root;
      $(item).find("[fold-button]").each(function(index, el) {  groupOpen.bind(this)(); });
    }
    this.closeAllFold = function(item) {
      item = item || this.root;
      $(item).find("[fold-button]").each(function(index, el) { groupClose.bind(this)(); })
    }
    function saveSingle(el) {
      el = el || this;
      return Object.assign({ children: [] },  el.data, { checked: el.checked });
    }

    // ---- Sets options and calls `this.load` ----
    var defaultOptions = { showAlwaysCheckBox: true, fold: true, openAllFold: true }
    options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);
    if(options.openAllFold){ this.openAllFold(); } else { this.closeAllFold(); }
    this.load(datas);


    // ---- GROUP EVENTS ----
    function groupOpen(){ $(this).parent().find(">.group").slideDown("fast"); }
    function groupClose() { $(this).parent().find(">.group").slideUp("fast"); }
    function groupToggle(){ $(this).parent().find(">.group").slideToggle("fast"); }

    // ---- ITEM EVENTS ----
    function changeCheckState(value, allChildCheck) {
      var c = this.checked;
      if (value != null && !(value instanceof MouseEvent)){c = value; }
      else{ if(c == 0){ c = 1; } else if(c == 1 || c == 2){ c-- } }       
      this.checked = c;
      setCheckState.bind(this)(c);
      if (c != 2){ checkAllChilds.bind(this)(c); checkControlParents.bind(this)(); }
    }
    function checkAllChilds(value) {
      var $group = $(this).parent(".group");
      $group.find(".item").each(function(index, el) { setCheckState.bind(el)(value); })
    }
    function checkControlParents() {
      var $parents = $(this).parents(".tabletreeview .group");
      for (var index = 1; index < $parents.length; index++) {
        var el = $parents[index]; item = $(el).find(">.item").get(0); $children = $(el).find(".group .item"); var all1 = true; var all0 = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i++) { if ($children[i].checked != 1) all1 = false; if ($children[i].checked != 0) all0 = false; }
        if(all1){ setCheckState.bind(item)(1); } else if(all0){ setCheckState.bind(item)(0); } else setCheckState.bind(item)(2);
      }
    }
    function setCheckState(value) {
      this.checked = value; this.setAttribute("check-value", value)
      if(value == 0){ $(this).find(">[check-icon]")[0].className = "fa fa-circle-thin"; }
      if(value == 1){ $(this).find(">[check-icon]")[0].className = "fa fa-check-circle-o"; }
      if(value == 2){ $(this).find(">[check-icon]")[0].className = "fa fa-dot-circle-o"; }
    }
    
    function createTreeViewReq(parentNode, datas, options, depth){
      // Takes `parentNode` (a row or table), `datas` (array of objects),
      //   `options` (object), and `depth` (integer)
      // Appends rows to parentNode -- kludgy b/c `tr` elements are nested
      for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++){
        if(datas[i] != null){
          var
            data = datas[i],
            item = createSingleItem(data, depth);
          parentNode.appendChild(item);
          if("children" in data && data.children.length > 0){
            createTreeViewReq(item, data.children, options, depth + 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function createSingleItem(data, depth) {
      // Takes a `data` object (w/ .text, .checked, .color & .children)
      // Returns a `tr` (w/ spacer, foldButton, item, and color)

      // Defines width values
      const TOP_ITEM_WIDTH = 300, SPACER_WIDTH = 20;

      // Makes a row (aka `group`) 
      var group = document.createElement("tr");
      group.className = "group"
      if("className" in options){ group.className += options.className; }

      // Adds a `spacer` cell to the row
      var spacer = document.createElement("td");
      spacer.style.width = `${SPACER_WIDTH}px`;
      group.appendChild(spacer);

      // Conditionally adds a `foldButton` 
      if("fold" in options){
        var foldButton = document.createElement("i");
        foldButton.className = "fa fa-caret-right";
        foldButton.setAttribute("fold-button", 1);
        foldButton.onclick = groupToggle.bind(foldButton);
        foldButton.isOpened = options.fold;
        group.appendChild(foldButton);
      }

      // Makes `item` (`showing data.text`, w/ all data attributes from `data`)
      var item = document.createElement("td");
      // Hack to align color cells
      item.style.width = `${ TOP_ITEM_WIDTH - (depth * (SPACER_WIDTH + 4)) }px`;
      item.className = "item";
      item.innerHTML = data.text;
      item.data = data;
      for(var keys = Object.keys(data), i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        item.setAttribute("data-" + keys[i], data[keys[i]]);
      }
      // Handles check-related events
      if ("checked" in data || options.showAlwaysCheckBox == true) {
        var checked = document.createElement("i");
        checked.setAttribute("check-icon", "1");
        checked.className = "fa ";
        item.prepend(checked);
        if ("checked" in data && data.checked) { setCheckState.bind(item)(data.checked ? 1 : 0); }
        else { setCheckState.bind(item)(0); }
      }
      item.onclick = changeCheckState.bind(item);

      // Adds item cell to the row
      group.appendChild(item);

      // Adds color cell to the row
      var colorLi = document.createElement("td");
      colorLi.classList.add("color");
      colorLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.color));
      group.appendChild(colorLi);

      return group;
    }
  }
```

```css
/* Note: some of your original styles may not be appropriate for HTML tables */

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.tabletreeview,
.tabletreeview * {
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.tabletreeview .item {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
}

.tabletreeview .color {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
}

.tabletreeview .item:hover {
  background: #DDD;
}

.tabletreeview .group [fold-button] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabletreeview .group [fold-button]:hover {
  background: #AAA;
}

.tabletreeview .item i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabletreeview .item[check-value="2"] {
  color: #595;
}

.tabletreeview .item[check-value="1"] {
  color: #5A5;
}

.tabletreeview .item[check-value="0"] {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="treeview.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <link href="css/jquery.tabletreeview.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is not treetable, i want to make treetable (i mean something like `<td>Parent 1</td> <td>blue</td>` )

Comment: Oh, I see. Your original example showed something else. I'll see if I can come up with an idea for you.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? I was messing around with it yesterday but don't want to put in any more time if you already have a solution.

Comment: I went ahead and finished the table-based solution. (See the edited answer.)